# Select immediate smaller/larger values when comparing multiple columns to another single column

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a variable number of columns, lets say for this example, we have 4 columns to be compared (`textX`) with a single column with different values (`id`):

```
d =     [
  {'id':  500, 'text1': 1000 ,'text2': 2000 ,'text3': 3000, 'text4': 5000}, 
  {'id': 1500, 'text1': 1000 ,'text2': 2000 ,'text3': 3000, 'text4': 5000},
  {'id': 2500, 'text1': 1000 ,'text2': 2000 ,'text3': 3000, 'text4': 5000},
  {'id': 3500, 'text1': 1000 ,'text2': 2000 ,'text3': 3000, 'text4': 5000},
  {'id': 4500, 'text1': 1000 ,'text2': 2000 ,'text3': 3000, 'text4': 5000},
  {'id': 5500, 'text1': 1000 ,'text2': 2000 ,'text3': 3000, 'text4': 5000}
] 
data = spark.createDataFrame(d)
```

I want to operate on both the immediate smallest and larger values from the `textX` columns depending on the value of 'id'.
For example, for `id` value = 2500, I would like to operate on the values 2000 and 3000. In the case of 'id' of value 500, it would be a null and 1000.
I have tried to get these as additional columns for example to get the lower column value

```
df_cols = data.columns
thresh_list = [x for x in df_cols if x.startswith('text')]

data.withColumn('inic_th', (col(x) for x in thresh_list if col('id') > col(x)))
```

But get an error :

> col should be Column

I guess this is because there are more than one columns that match the condition but cannot get to insert that here.

Does anyone have any solution to either get an operation into 2 values depending on a third column or just how to properly get these bounds? In reality, the number of `textX` columns will vary. Due to performance issues, I am steering away from Pandas and UDFs as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `least` and `greatest` to get the relevant columns:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = data.withColumn(
    'col1',
    F.greatest(*[
        F.when(F.col(c) < F.col('id'), F.col(c))
        for c in data.columns
    ])
).withColumn(
    'col2',
    F.least(*[
        F.when(F.col(c) > F.col('id'), F.col(c))
        for c in data.columns
    ])
)

df.show()
+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+----+----+
|  id|text1|text2|text3|text4|col1|col2|
+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+----+----+
| 500| 1000| 2000| 3000| 5000|null|1000|
|1500| 1000| 2000| 3000| 5000|1000|2000|
|2500| 1000| 2000| 3000| 5000|2000|3000|
|3500| 1000| 2000| 3000| 5000|3000|5000|
|4500| 1000| 2000| 3000| 5000|3000|5000|
|5500| 1000| 2000| 3000| 5000|5000|null|
+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+----+----+
```

And then you can operate on `col1` and `col2`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way using higher order functions for spark >=2.4:

---

```
df_cols = data.columns
thresh_list = [x for x in df_cols if x.startswith('text')]

out = (data.select("*",F.sort_array(F.array(*thresh_list)).alias("Arr"))
.withColumn("FirstVal",F.expr('element_at(filter (Arr, x-> x<id),-1)'))
.withColumn("LastVal",F.expr('filter (Arr, x->x>id)[0]')).drop("Arr")
)
```

---

```
out.show(truncate=False)

+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+--------+-------+
|id  |text1|text2|text3|text4|FirstVal|LastVal|
+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+--------+-------+
|500 |1000 |2000 |3000 |5000 |null    |1000   |
|1500|1000 |2000 |3000 |5000 |1000    |2000   |
|2500|1000 |2000 |3000 |5000 |2000    |3000   |
|3500|1000 |2000 |3000 |5000 |3000    |5000   |
|4500|1000 |2000 |3000 |5000 |3000    |5000   |
|5500|1000 |2000 |3000 |5000 |5000    |null   |
+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+--------+-------+
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way using [`array_max`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.array_max) and [`array_min`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.array_min) functions along with [`when`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.when) expressions :

- `lowerBound` = max `thresh_cols` that statisfy condition `thresh_col < id`
- `upperBound` = min `thresh_cols` that statisfy condition `thresh_col > id`

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

result = data.withColumn(
    'lowerBound',
    F.array_max(F.array(*[F.when(F.col(c) < F.col('id'), F.col(c)) for c in thresh_cols]))
).withColumn(
    'upperBound',
    F.array_min(F.array(*[F.when(F.col(c) > F.col('id'), F.col(c)) for c in thresh_cols]))
)

result.show()

#+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+----------+----------+
#|  id|text1|text2|text3|text4|lowerBound|upperBound|
#+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+----------+----------+
#| 500| 1000| 2000| 3000| 5000|      null|      1000|
#|1500| 1000| 2000| 3000| 5000|      1000|      2000|
#|2500| 1000| 2000| 3000| 5000|      2000|      3000|
#|3500| 1000| 2000| 3000| 5000|      3000|      5000|
#|4500| 1000| 2000| 3000| 5000|      3000|      5000|
#|5500| 1000| 2000| 3000| 5000|      5000|      null|
#+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+----------+----------+
```